# Why aren't generic constraints not picked up by useFormContext

Tags: typescript, react-hook-form

I want to write a reusable component to enter a name in a form. Here is my code

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form';
    import { TextField, FormGroup } from '@mui/material';
    
    interface IName {
      name: string;
    }
    
    function NameSelector<FormValues extends IName>() {
      const {
        register,
        setValue,
        formState: { errors },
      } = useFormContext<FormValues>();
    
      return (
        <form>
          <FormGroup>
            <TextField
              {...register('name', { minLength: 2, required: false })}
              // Argument of type '"name"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Path<FormValues>'
              onBlur={(e: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                setValue('name', e.target.value);
              }}
              error={Boolean(errors.name)}
              helperText={errors.name && 'This field is required'}
              label="name"
            />
          </FormGroup>
        </form>
      );
    }
    
    export default NameSelector;
```

If I replace useFormContext<FormValues>() by useFormContext<IName>(), the error disappears.

It seems the type checker is not picking up that FormValues extends IName
Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying (ie writing a reusable component while maintaining a strict type checking on property names)? What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually using useFormContext<IName>();
It seems to have the desired effect (ie strong type checking), and I just have a warning about 'FormValues' being declared but never read.